# Mostrar o conteúdo duma lista recursivamente

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Estamos a estudar a recursividade no nosso curso de programação, e temos um exercício onde temos que mostrar no *idle* o conteúdo duma lista usando a recursividade. Eu fi-lo assim:

```py
def print_list_r(ls=[], n=0):
    if len(ls) == 0 or n < 0:
        return False
    if n < len(ls):
        print(ls[n])
    else:
        return
    print_list_r(ls, n+1)
```

Este é um bom algoritmo? É possível fazer este algoritmo sem usar o parâmetro `n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é um bom algoritmo. Todos os testes relevantes foram feitos (condição de parada ok, limite dos índices ok), aliás o teste por `len(ls) == 0` é meio que redundante: se `n >= 0` - condição necessária para se passar pelo primeiro `if` - for verdadeira, então a condição `n < len(ls)` só será verdadeira se `len(ls) > 0`. Não há cópia desnecessária de objetos (a mesma lista é usada sempre) e ainda está presente a [recursão de cauda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/215) - se a implementação se aproveitar disso, seu código pode ser tão eficiente quanto um iterativo (infelizmente [não parece ser o caso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591970/520779) com CPython).

O que eu não entendi é por que você retorna `False` se a lista estiver vazia e `None` caso contrário. Eu até entendo que você pode querer dar uma saída diferente se `n` for inválido (negativo), mas uma lista vazia, na minha concepção, deveria ser uma entrada válida - tratada de forma indistinta das demais entradas.

Quanto a fazer sem usar o parâmetro `n`, é possível sim, embora de forma ineficiente:

```
def print_list_r(ls=[]):
    if len(ls) > 0:
        print(ls[0])
        print_list_r(ls[1:])
```

Ou seja, se a lista não estiver vazia, imprima o primeiro elemento e chame a função recursivamente passando como argumento a sublista com os índices `1`em diante (terminando com uma sublista vazia).