# Porquê esta função mostra a lista antes de retornar mas retorna None

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Estou a escrever uma função que capitalize todos os elementos string duma lista recursivamente, mas ela retorna "estranhamente" None, mas antes de retornar mostra corretamente a lista capitalizada:

```
def cap_str_elems_r(ls=[], new_list=[]):
    if len(ls)>0:
        if isinstance(ls[0], str):
            new_list.append(ls[0].capitalize())
        else:
            new_list.append(ls[0])
    else:
        print(new_list)
        return new_list
    cap_str_elems_r(ls[1:], new_list)
#
ls=["hip", 14, "to", "hop", 12]
new_list = cap_str_elems_r(ls)
print(new_list) # amostra None
```

Comment: É porque quando não entra no `else` ele não retorna nada. Mude a última linha pra `return cap_str_elems_r(ls[1:], new_list)`

Comment: Sim, mas o que é retornado é o valor de retorno da primeira chamada (não da última). P.S. Vou explicar melhor em uma resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando uma função - recursiva ou não - é chamada, o que interessa pra função chamadora é o valor de retorno dela. Não das funções que ela chama. Por exemplo:

```
def fatorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * fatorial(n-1)
```

Nesse caso, a última chamada recursiva vai retornar um valor, mas esse valor só será usado pela **chamada anterior a ela**. É preciso repassar esse valor (possivelmente modificado, como no exemplo acima) para a função "acima" dela, até chegar na função chamadora.

Uma outra maneira de se escrever a função `fatorial` acima é usando um **acumulador** - o que evita que novas operações sejam feitas após a chamada recursiva, consistindo então numa [recursão de cauda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/215):

```
def fatorial(n, acc=1): # Acumula o valor 1 inicialmente
    if n == 1:
        return acc # Retorna o valor acumulado, não 1
    return fatorial(n-1, acc * n) # Acumula o valor n no produtório
```

Essa foi a mesma estratégia que você usou, no caso acumulando `new_list`. Mas note que, mesmo sendo de cauda, é necessário usar o `return` no final, pra chamada `n` ter acesso à `n-1`, a `n-1` ter acesso à `n-2`, etc, até que a função chamadora tenha acesso à função original.

Se você não retornar nada, no Python isso significa que o valor de retorno será `None`. Modifique então sua última linha para:

```
return cap_str_elems_r(ls[1:], new_list)
```