# problema superfatorial recursivo

Tags: c#, c, recursão

Estou com uma duvida na realização desta função recursiva de matematica.

Calculo do superfatorial:

O superfatorial de um número N é definida pelo produto dos N primeiros fatoriais
de N. Assim, o superfatorial de 4 é
**sf(4) = 1! * 2! * 3! * 4! = 288**
Faça uma função recursiva que receba um número inteiro positivo N e retorne o superfatorial desse número.

Meu código:

```
int super (int n, int m) {
   if (m == 1) return 1;
   if (n == 1) return super (m - 1, m - 1);
   return n * super(n - 1, m);
}
```

Ao chamar a função, super (n, n), o valor do superfatorial de n é devolvido corretamente.
Observe que utilizei dois parametros, n e m.
O parametro m de auxiliar para realização da função. **Esta é a minha dúvida, pois na questão ele pede apenas um parametro (n).** Eu não consegui pensar em uma maneira de faze-la com um paramentro super(n). É possivel?

Agradeço desde ja.

Comment: Duas tags de duas linguagens diferentes, o problema pode ser resolvido em qualquer uma das duas?

Comment: Você tem que fazer tudo em uma única função ou podem ser duas? Por exemplo, um fatorial e a superfatorial?

Comment: A ideia do exercio  é essa.

Comment: chama-lhe `superaux`e cria outra função `int super(int n){ return superaux(n,n);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode não ter tanta relevância nesse caso (pois o valor do fatorial - e consequentemente do superfatorial - cresce tão rápido que é inviável calculá-lo para números grandes), mas o modo como você e os demais respondentes estão calculando possui uma ineficiência, que é calcular de novo e de novo componentes usados em diversas partes do cálculo (como já apontado por user2856432). Ao calcular `4!` por exemplo você já calcula `3!`, melhor usar esse resultado depois que calcular `3!` novamente no próximo termo. A complexidade no caso é quadrática com o valor do argumento.

Vou mostrar uma alternativa aqui, nem tanto pelo problema em si (que como já falei, é inviável fazer para números grandes) mas para demonstrar uma técnica muito útil quando se trabalha com recursão - o **acumulador**:

```
int sfat(n) {
    return sfat2(1, n, 1); // Vai de 1 a n, e o valor acumulado é 1
}

int sfat2(inicio, fim, acumulador) {
    if ( inicio > fim )
        return acumulador;
    return acumulador * sfat2(inicio+1, fim, inicio*acumulador);
}
```

Explicando, caso não tenha ficado claro o que o código está fazendo:

- A chamada inicial passa `0! = 1` como acumulador, e o intervalo vai de `1` a `n`;
- A primeira chamada - termo `1` - multiplica esse `(n-1)! = (1-1)! = 0!` pelo resultado da chamada recursiva, que por sua vez recebe como acumulador `n*(n-1)! = 1*(1-1)! = 1*0! = 1!`;

  - O resultado é `0! * sfat(1)`
- A segunda chamada - termo `2` - multiplica esse `(n-1)! = (2-1)! = 1!` pelo resultado da chamada recursiva, que por sua vez recebe como acumulador `n*(n-1)! = 2*(2-1)! = 2*1! = 2!`;

  - O resultado é `0! * 1! * sfat(2)`
- A terceira chamada - termo `3` - multiplica esse `(n-1)! = (3-1)! = 2!` pelo resultado da chamada recursiva, que por sua vez recebe como acumulador `n*(n-1)! = 3*(3-1)! = 3*2! = 3!`;

  - O resultado é `0! * 1! * 2! * sfat(2)`
- ...
- A enésima chamada - termo `n` - multiplica esse `(n-1)!` pelo resultado da chamada recursiva, que por sua vez recebe como acumulador `n*(n-1)!`;

  - O resultado é `0! * 1! * 2! * ... * (n-1)! * sfat(n+1)`
- A chamada seguinte - termo `n+1` - encontra a condição de parada, retornando o acumulador `((n+1) - 1)! = n!`;

  - O resultado é `0! * 1! * 2! * ... * (n-1)! * n!`

Como você pode ver, o número de chamadas recursivas agora é linear com o valor do argumento.

**Nota**: se você quisesse implementar a [**recursão de cauda**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/215) - em que a chamada recursiva é a última operação executada (útil em linguagens cujo compilador otimiza esse tipo de chamada, transformando-a em iterativa) - você poderia fazer isso através de dois acumuladores: um para o fatorial, e outro pro resultado:

```
int sfat(n) {
    return sfat2(1, n, 1, 1); // Acumula (n-1)! e o resultado
}

int sfat2(inicio, fim, fat_acc, sfat_acc) {
    if ( inicio > fim )
        return sfat_acc;
    return sfat2(inicio+1, fim, inicio*fat_acc, inicio*fat_acc*sfat_acc);
}
```

[Exemplos no ideone](https://ideone.com/3CxFsU).

Answer (score 4):

Olá, eu resolveria criando uma função adicional, sem mudar nada desta que você postou.
É basicamente o que você mesmo falou, só que não fazer isso no main, lá seria chamada a superfat, que tem só **um parâmetro**.

```
int super (int n, int m) {
   if (m == 1){
        return 1;
   }
   if (n == 1){
        return super (m - 1, m - 1);
   }
   return n * super(n - 1, m);
}

int superfat (int n){
    return super(n, n);
}

int main(){

    printf("%d", superfat(4)); //288

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é usar uma função fatorial(n), e assim a função super(n) fica recursiva sem precisar de uma auxiliar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    //return n*fact(n-1); /* descomentar aqui se preferir definição recursiva (pior performance) /*

    int result = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        result = n*result;
        n--;
    }
    return result;
}

int super(n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fact(n)*super(n-1);
}

int main() {
    printf("Result fact(%d): %d\n", 4, super(4));
    return 0;
}
```

Vale lembrar que esta implementação não é ótima, visto que a cada recursão de super() diversos fatoriais que já foram calculados antes são novamente calculados. (Para um problema real que envolva fatorial eu imagino que o mais eficiente seja ter um conjunto de valores tabelados mesmo).

Mas para sua pergunta essa resposta é suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Praticamente o que o user2856432 falou só que de maneira mais compacta:

```
int fat(int val){
       if(!val) return 1;
       else return val * fat(val-1);       
}

int sfat(int val){
       if(!val) return 1;
       else return fat(val) * sfat(val-1);
}
```