# O que é uma função recursiva?

Tags: terminologia, recursão

Sempre ouvi falar que recursividade é uma ideia inteligente que desempenha um papel central na programação funcional e na ciência da computação em geral. Pelo que entendi, sucintamente, existe recursividade **mútua** e **cauda**.

O que é uma função recursiva? Quais são as principais caracteristicas entre recursividade mútua e de cauda?

Comment: Além do óbvio que já tem em [outras perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recurs%c3%a3o), acho que só caberia uma resposta mais acadêmica, por isso vou deixar outras pessoas responder.

Comment: Em complemento às respostas, dou o exemplo do fatorial matemático, que utiliza da recursividade (ref.: `(n+1)! = n! * (n+1)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma função recursiva é uma função que chama a si mesma.

Elas podem ser usadas para poder processar uma determinada operação e geralmente há condições internas para que a recursividades sejam aplicadas (uma vez que sem condições, ela chamaria a si mesmo eternamente, causando o que chamamos de loop infinito).

Por exemplo, um trecho da minha biblioteca para carregamento preguiçoso de ajax pelo Angular (framework para Javascript):

```
WMLaravelLazyLoad.prototype.untilCompleted = function () {

    var that = this;

    that.next().then(function () {
        that.untilCompleted();
    })
};
```

No exemplo acima, quando a ação é concluída, a função é chamada imediatamente, porém até que `next()` possua algum retorno que faça com que o código de `then` seja acionado.

Eu havia feito uma pergunta onde é abordado o uso da recursividade, que apesar de ser um pouco diferente, dá pra se ter ideia da vantagem em utilizá-la.

[Por que dizem que recursividade de setTimeout é melhor que setInterval?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77764/por-que-dizem-que-recursividade-de-settimeout-%C3%A9-melhor-que-setinterval)

Sobre a pergunta sobre recursividade mútua e de cauda, você pode ver:

[Qual a diferença entre recursão e recursão de cauda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4282/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-recurs%C3%A3o-e-recurs%C3%A3o-de-cauda)

Answer (score 1):

A função é recursiva é uma função que chama a si mesma, sempre.

Ela na verdade é horrível, principalmente para o tratamento e gerenciamento de memória.

**EXEMPLO DE FUNÇÃO RECURSIVA**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void movetorre (int n, char orig, char dest, char aux){
   if (n==1) {printf("\nMover disco 1 da torre %c para a torre %c", orig, dest);
   return;}
      movetorre(n-1,orig,aux,dest);
      printf("\nMover disco %d da torre %c para a torre %c", n, orig, dest);
      movetorre(n-1,aux,dest,orig);
};

int main(){
   int discos;
   printf("\t\t\t\tTORRE DE HANOY\n\n");
   printf("Digite a quantidade de discos: ");
   scanf("%d",&discos);
   movetorre(discos,'A','C','B');
   return 0;
}
```

Esse é um exemplo simples de um algoritmo, com recursividade, chamado torre de hanoi, feito em c.

Você pode reparar que ela chama a si mesma.

**RECURSIVIDADE MÚTUA**

Recursividade mútua ocorre quando duas ou mais funções são definidas em termos uma da outra.

O exemplo básico mais importante de um tipo de dados que pode ser definido por recursão mútua é uma árvore, que pode ser mutuamente definida recursivamente em termos de uma floresta (uma lista de árvores).

**RECURSIVIDADE EM CAUDA**

As funções recursivas em cauda formam uma subclasse das funções recursivas, nas quais a chamada recursiva é a última instrução a ser executada.

Comment: "Ela na verdade é horrível". Aí já entra questões de opinião. Seria melhor formular prós e contras.

Comment: Sim, ela é horrível, cada vez que chama ela, armazena um dado na memória, onde que para desempilhar, é um saco.

Analisando por exemplo, o algoritmo, torre de hanoi, ele é recursivo e se torna o ^ n... ou seja, tem estouro de memória muito fácil

Comment: Você está falando especificamente da linguagem C? Tem que prestar atenção porque o AP está questionando sobre o conceito num âmbito geral.

Comment: Não, estou falando sobre estrutura de dados em si

Comment: Hmmmmm. Não entendi. Como assim 'desempilhar' é um saco @gabrielfalieri? Isso é transparente para você, no entanto, concordo, claro, que dependendo da memória HEAP disponivel e da quantidade de vezes que a recursão for executada a memória não será suficiente.

Comment: Reginaldo Rigo, quando você chama a função, ele vai salvando na memória, vai salvando na memória, vai salvando na memória, vai salvando da memória, depois que desempilha, quando chegar no resultado desejado. Isso gera estouro de memória