# Jquery: calcular número de cédulas do valor de saque (entregar o menor numero possível)

Tags: jquery

Estou resolvendo um exercício que estou com dúvidas, é referente a um sistema de banco, no qual ao apresentar o valor de saque, devo receber o menor numero de notas possíveis para o valor indicado, também devo utilizar o método recursivo. 
Segue abaixo o que já fiz até o momento:

Questão: Sistema de saque
- Saque R$ 80,00;
- Caixa retorna 1 nota R$ 50,00;
- Caixa retorna 1 nota R$ 20,00;
- Caixa retorna 1 nota R$ 10,00.

Deve ser devolvidas o menor número de notas possíveis.
Notas disponíveis: R$ 100,00, R$ 50,00, R$ 20,00, R$ 10,00 R$ 5,00 R$ 2,00.
O resto (Valor que não possa ser retornado com cédulas disponíveis) deve ser impresso caso existir.

O código:

```
var saque = 22;
var contador100 = 0;
var contador50 = 0;
var contador20 = 0;
var contador10 = 0;
var contador5 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;

if(saque != 0) {
if(saque >= 100) {
    contador100++;
    saque =- 100;
}

if(saque >= 50) {
    contador50++;
    saque =- 50;
}

if(saque >= 20) {
    contador20++;
    saque =- 20;
}

if(saque >= 10) {
    contador10++;
    saque =- 10;
}

if(saque >= 5) {
    contador5++;
    saque =- 5;
}

if(saque >= 2) {
    contador2++;
    saque =- 2;
}
}

console.log("A quantidade de notas 100 é: " + contador100);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 50 é: " + contador50);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 20 é: " + contador20);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 10 é: " + contador10);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 5 é: " + contador5);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 2 é: " + contador2);
```

Mas por algum motivo, esse código considera apenas a primeira nota, por exemplo, no saque de 22 reais, ele vai me apresentar apenas uma nota de 20 e desconsidera os 2 reais.

Comment: A dúvida seria em como utilizar o método recursivamente?

Comment: Seria como fazer essa questão de sacar com as menores notas possíveis e implementando no metodo recursivo.

Comment: @mercador Eu alterei o código, mas por algum motivo ainda não consigo fazer funcionar 100%.

Comment: Eu usei seu código e corrigi ele para que vc entendesse as falhas nele e não prejudicar seu aprendizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta que divida pela maior cédula e ir diminuindo, isso segue a mesma ideia da resposta do [@MagicHat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215453/15089).

```js
var notasDisponiveis = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2];

function calcularNotasNecessarias(valor, tentativa, resultado) {

  if (notasDisponiveis[tentativa] === undefined) {
    resultado.resto = valor;
    return resultado;
  }

  divisao = Math.floor(valor / notasDisponiveis[tentativa]);

  if (divisao > 0) {
    valor -= divisao * notasDisponiveis[tentativa];
    resultado.notas[notasDisponiveis[tentativa]] = divisao;
  }

  return calcularNotasNecessarias(valor, ++tentativa, resultado);
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="console.log(calcularNotasNecessarias(this.value, 0, {resto: 0, notas: {}}))">
```

A ideia é bem simples, supondo que seja o valor 99, você terá:

```
 99/100 = 0.99 -> (Arredonda para baixo) -> 0
 99/50  = 1.98 -> (Arredonda para baixo) -> 1, indica que precisa de 1 nota de 50.
 49/20  = 2.45 -> (Arredonda para baixo) -> 2, indica que precisa de 2 notas de 20.
  9/10  = 0.90 -> (Arredonda para baixo) -> 0
  9/5   = 1.80 -> (Arredonda para baixo) -> 1, indica que precisa de 1 nota de 5.
  4/2   = 2.00 -> (Arredonda para baixo) -> 2, indica que precisa de 2 notas de 2.
Resto: 0
```

É exatamente isso que ele faz.

Comment: Era na lógica dessa divisão que eu não estava conseguindo chegar, obrigada !

Answer (score 5):

Resolvi postar uma solução, que ao meu ver mais se aproxima do que está sendo pedido:

Primeiro precisa entender o que é recursividade, está fora do escopo desta resposta, mas pode obter mais informações em [recursividade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade) e um pouco aqui mesmo no SOpt [nessa outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186269/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursiva).

Isto posto, para teu exercício, seria algo assim:

```html
<body onload="notaQtd(not,ent)">
<script>
function notaQtd(notas,entrada)
{   for(var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++)
    {   if(entrada >= notas[i])
        {   var notaM = notas[i];
        }
    }
    var numN = entrada / notaM;
    console.log(Math.floor(numN) + " notas de : " + notaM);
    resto = parseFloat(entrada % notaM);
    if((resto != 0) && (resto > 1))
    {   notaQtd(notas,resto);
    }else if(resto != 0)
    {   console.log("Sobrou :" + resto);
    }
}
var not = [2,5,10,20,50,100];
var ent  = prompt("Digite o valor do saque(apenas números inteiros sem pontos):\nNotas disponíveis(100,50,20,10,5,2)");
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

### No tempo do vovô fazíamos assim:

```js
var valor  = prompt("Valor do saque(apenas números inteiros sem pontos)");

var qtd100 = parseInt(valor/100);
console.log("notas de 100: " + qtd100);

var resto = (valor-(qtd100*100));
var qtd50 = parseInt(resto/50);
console.log("notas de 50: " + qtd50);

resto = (valor-((qtd100*100)+(qtd50*50)));
var qtd20 = parseInt(resto/20);
console.log("notas de 20: " + qtd20);

resto = (valor-((qtd100*100)+(qtd50*50)+(qtd20*20)));
var qtd10 = parseInt(resto/10);
console.log("notas de 10: " + qtd10);

resto = (valor-((qtd100*100)+(qtd50*50)+(qtd20*20)+(qtd10*10)));
var qtd5 = parseInt(resto/5);
console.log("notas de 5: " + qtd5);

resto = (valor-((qtd100*100)+(qtd50*50)+(qtd20*20)+(qtd10*10)+(qtd5*5)));
var qtd2 = parseInt(resto/2);
console.log("notas de 2: " + qtd2);

resto = (valor-((qtd100*100)+(qtd50*50)+(qtd20*20)+(qtd10*10)+(qtd5*5)+(qtd2*2)));

if (resto==1){
console.log("restou: " + resto);
}
```

### Para efeito de aprendizado no seu script temos as seguintes correções:

Inversão em  `saque =-` por  `saque -=` em todas as linhas

Por exemplo:   `saque =-20;`  retorna -20

> sinal de igual (=) é atribuição. saque=-20; atribui o valor (-20) à variável saque

e  `saque -= 20;` retorna 2

> [**Operador de atribuição de subtração (-=)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dtx39exz(v=vs.94).aspx)
>
> [**Expressões e operadores**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Usar loop  `for` ou  `while` para que o objetivo seja alcançado de forma satisfatória pois com  `ifs` não há recursividade e valores acima de 187, não funciona.  [**Laços e iterações**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Lacos_e_iteracoes)

### 1 - Laço de repetição for

```js
//somente para teste ficar dinamico
var saque = entrada  = prompt("Valor do saque(apenas números inteiros sem pontos)");

//var saque = entrada =  266;
var contador100 = 0;
var contador50 = 0;
var contador20 = 0;
var contador10 = 0;
var contador5 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;


if(saque != 0) {
for(;saque >= 100;) {
    contador100++;
    saque -= 100;
}
for(;saque >= 50;) {
    contador50++;
    saque -= 50;
}

for(;saque >= 20;) {
    contador20++;
    saque -= 20;
}

for(;saque >= 10;) {
    contador10++;
    saque -= 10;
}

for(;saque >= 5;) {
    contador5++;
    saque -= 5;
}

for(;saque >= 2;) {
    contador2++;
    saque -= 2;
}

}
var total = (contador100*100+contador50*50+contador20*20+contador10*10+contador5*5+contador2*2);
var resto = entrada - total;

console.log("A quantidade de notas 100 é: " + contador100);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 50 é: " + contador50);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 20 é: " + contador20);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 10 é: " + contador10);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 5 é: " + contador5);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 2 é: " + contador2);
if (resto!=0){
console.log("O resto é: " + resto);
}
```

### 2 -  Laço de repetição while

```js
var saque = entrada  = prompt("Valor do saque(apenas números inteiros sem pontos)");

var contador100 = 0;
var contador50 = 0;
var contador20 = 0;
var contador10 = 0;
var contador5 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;


if(saque != 0) {
while (saque >= 100) {
    contador100++;
    saque -= 100;
}
while (saque >= 50) {
    contador50++;
    saque -= 50;
}

while (saque >= 20) {
    contador20++;
    saque -= 20;
}

while (saque >= 10) {
    contador10++;
    saque -= 10;
}

while (saque >= 10) {
    contador5++;
    saque -= 5;
}

while (saque >= 2) {
    contador2++;
    saque -= 2;
}

}
var total = (contador100*100+contador50*50+contador20*20+contador10*10+contador5*5+contador2*2);
var resto = entrada - total;

console.log("A quantidade de notas 100 é: " + contador100);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 50 é: " + contador50);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 20 é: " + contador20);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 10 é: " + contador10);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 5 é: " + contador5);
console.log("A quantidade de notas 2 é: " + contador2);
if (resto!=0){
console.log("O resto é: " + resto);
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigada! Sabe me explicar qual a diferença entre o =- e o -=?