# Obter a quantidade de números ímpares, posições dos pares e média dos positivos, a partir de uma tupla de números

Tags: python

Tenho que declarar uma tupla com 10 números inteiros e preciso encontrar a quantidade de numeros ímpares (já feito), as posições dos números pares (preciso de ajuda para essa lógica) e a média dos números positivos (preciso de ajuda na lógica para calcular a soma dos números positivos).

```
tupla = (1, 2, -1, 0, 3, 7, 9, -3, -4, 0)

#a) Quantidade de números ímpares
def impares(tupla):
    if not tupla:
        return 0

    impar = (tupla[0] % 2 != 0)

    if impar:
        return 1 + impares(tupla[1:])
    else:
        return impares(tupla[1:])
print ("Quantidade de números ímpares: ", impares(tupla[0:]))     

#b) Posição dos números pares

#preciso de ajuda na lógica desse ítem



#c) Média dos números positivos

#quantidade de positivos pra calcular a média
def posit(tupla):
    if not tupla:
        return 0

    pos = (tupla[0] > 0)

    if pos:
        return 1 + posit(tupla[1:])
    else:
        return posit(tupla[1:])
#print (posit(tupla[0:]))

#soma números positivos
#preciso de ajuda para calcular a soma
def somaPos(tupla):
  soma = 0
  for elemento in tupla:
    if elemento >0:
     soma = soma+elemento
  print(soma)

media = somap/posit(tupla[0:])      
print ("Média dos números positivos", media)
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é exigência do exercício fazer cada coisa em uma função separada, e ainda mais [funções recursivas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186269/112052), sendo que não há **nenhuma** necessidade de usar recursão e ainda dá para fazer tudo em um único *loop*:

```
tupla = (1, 2, -1, 0, 3, 7, 9, -3, -4, 0)
soma = qtd_impares = qtd_positivos = 0
posicoes = []
for i, n in enumerate(tupla):
    if n % 2 == 0: # número par, guarda posição
        posicoes.append(i)
    else: # número ímpar, atualiza quantidade 
        qtd_impares += 1

    if n > 0: # número positivo, atualiza soma e quantidade, para calcular a média no final
        soma += n
        qtd_positivos += 1

media = soma / qtd_positivos
print("quantidade de números ímpares", qtd_impares)
print("posições dos números pares", posicoes)
print("média dos números positivos", media)
```

O uso de [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) é para iterar pelos números ao mesmo tempo em que obtenho o índice (que é a posição do mesmo). Ou seja, a cada iteração do `for`, a variável `n` será um dos números e a variável `i` será o respectivo índice (ou seja, a posição do número).

Dentro do *loop* é só testar cada condição e fazer o que precisa em cada caso:

- se o número for par, eu guardo a posição (ou seja, o `i`). Como pode ter mais de um número par, estou usando uma lista para guardar todas as posições
- se o número for ímpar, atualizo a quantidade
- se o número for positivo, atualizo a soma deles e a quantidade (já que vou precisar de ambos para calcular a média no final)

---

Se quer separar cada coisa em uma função, você pode fazer assim:

```
tupla = (1, 2, -1, 0, 3, 7, 9, -3, -4, 0)

def qtd_impares(tupla):
    return len([n for n in tupla if n % 2 != 0])

def posicoes_pares(tupla):
    return [i for i, n in enumerate(tupla) if n % 2 == 0]

def media_positivos(tupla):
    positivos = [n for n in tupla if n > 0]
    return sum(positivos) / len(positivos)

print("quantidade de números ímpares", qtd_impares(tupla))
print("posições dos números pares", posicoes_pares(tupla))
print("média dos números positivos", media_positivos(tupla))
```

Usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052). Mas como é um exercício, talvez seja "exigido" que se faça manualmente:

```
def qtd_impares(tupla):
    qtd = 0
    for n in tupla:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            qtd += 1
    return qtd

def posicoes_pares(tupla):
    posicoes = []
    for i, n in enumerate(tupla):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            posicoes.append(i)
    return posicoes

def media_positivos(tupla):
    soma = qtd = 0
    for n in tupla:
        if n > 0:
            soma += n
            qtd += 1

    return soma / qtd
```

Outro detalhe é que você está passando `tupla[0:]` para as funções, mas não precisa disso. O [*slice*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) `[0:]` pega todos os elementos da tupla, então fazer `funcao(tupla)` ou `funcao(tupla[0:])` dá no mesmo.

Outro ponto é que cada uma das funções acima percorre todos os números da tupla, então ao chamá-las, você estará percorrendo-a 3 vezes. Já usando o primeiro código acima, a tupla é percorrida apenas uma vez (tudo bem que para um exercício, e para poucos valores, não faz tanta diferença assim).

---

Se quer mesmo usar recursão (que não faz sentido para este caso, e nem é a melhor solução), uma alternativa seria:

```
tupla = (1, 2, -1, 0, 3, 7, 9, -3, -4, 0)

def qtd_impares(tupla):
    if not tupla:
        return 0
    # se for ímpar, qtd é 1, senão é 0
    qtd = 1 if tupla[0] % 2 != 0 else 0
    return qtd + qtd_impares(tupla[1:])

def posicoes_pares(tupla, posicao=0):
    if posicao >= len(tupla):
        return []
    posicoes = []
    if tupla[posicao] % 2 == 0:
        posicoes.append(posicao)
    return posicoes + posicoes_pares(tupla, posicao + 1)

def media_recursiva(tupla, n = None):
    if n is None:
        n = len(tupla)
    if n == 1:
        return tupla[0]
    return (tupla[n - 1] + ((n - 1) * media_recursiva(tupla, n - 1))) / n

def media_positivos(tupla):
    return media_recursiva(tuple(filter(lambda n: n > 0, tupla)))

print("quantidade de números ímpares", qtd_impares(tupla))
print("posições dos números pares", posicoes_pares(tupla))
print("média dos números positivos", media_positivos(tupla))
```

[Além de não ser a melhor solução para este caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052), usar recursão ainda [pode causar um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) caso a tupla seja muito grande (já usando *loops*, não há esse problema). Sem contar que o código fica desnecessariamente mais complicado.