# Dúvida com função recursiva em C

Tags: c, funções, recursão

Boa noite, pessoal!

Estou realizando uma atividade cujo objetivo é usar uma função recursiva para realizar uma **divisão inteira apenas através de subtrações sucessivas**.

Fiz um laço usando while e somente ele (que rodei em um código a parte) deu certo. O problema está em usá-lo na função recursiva. Consegui fazê-lo compilar, mas o resultado não está correto.

Olhando o código ainda não encontrei o problema (pensei que fosse o *return i* na função, mas o resultado não foi alterado, ou talvez na declaração das variáveis - mas ainda não sei dizer)... Comecei a aprender funções recursivas há pouco tempo, caso alguém possa ajudar, agradeço *muito* a ajuda!

**Laço que dá certo sozinho:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    int a, b, i = 0;
    
    printf ("Digite o dividendo (numero que será dividido):");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    
    printf ("Digite o divisor:");
    scanf ("%d", &b);    
    
    
while (a > 0 && a >= b){
    a = a - b;
    i++;
}

    printf ("O resultado da divisao e: %d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Função recursiva que dá errado:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int a,b;
    
    printf ("Digite o dividendo (numero que será dividido): ");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    printf ("Digite o divisor: ");
    scanf ("%d", &b);  
    
    printf ("O resultado da divisao e: %d. \n", divide(a,b));

    
    return 0;
}

int divide (a,b){
    
    int i = 0;

    while (a > 0 && a >= b){
    a = a - b;
    i++;
    
    return i;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Erro do programa**

O erro da sua função está na posição do `return`, nesse trecho:

```
while (a > 0 && a >= b){
    a = a - b;
    i++;

    return i;
}
```

O comando `return` tem duas funcionalidades:

> 1. Encerra uma função
> 2. Encerra uma função devolvendo um valor

Com base nisso nota-se que quando o `while` é ativado ocorre essas três instruções:

> 1. O valor de a é subtraido
> 2. i é incrementado em 1
> 3. A função é encerrada devolvendo o valor de i

Se a função é encerrada logo após o valor de `i` aumentar em `1` então o `loop` que o `while` faz não ocorrerá e isso gera o resultado inesperado.

**Solução**

Para resolver este problema basta deixar o comando `return` fora da do `loop`, desta forma:

```
while (a > 0 && a >= b){
    a = a - b;
    i++;
}

return i;
```

Assim a função só será encerrada quando o `loop` terminar.

**Recursividade**

Mesmo depois de resolver o problema essa função não é [recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186269/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursiva).

Uma função recursiva é uma função que chama a se própria. Exemplo:

```
int funcao(int a) {
    // Alguns codigos

    funcao(a); // funcao chamando a si mesma

    // Mais codigos

    return a;
}
```

O trecho acima é um rascunho do que seria uma função recursiva. Uma observação é que devemos ter cuidado ao usar a recursividade para não criar um `loop` infinito.

**Trasnformando sua função em uma função recursiva**

Para que sua função seja recursiva é preciso que ela chame-se a si mesma. Exemplo:

```
int divide_recursivo(int a, int b) {
    int i = 0;

    if (a > 0 && a >= b) {
        a = a - b;
        i++;
        i += divide_recursivo(a, b); // a funcao chamando a si mesma
    }

    return i;
}
```

Na sua lógica usando o `while` o valor de `i` era incrementado ´n´ vezes dependendo desta expressão: `a > 0 && a >= b`. Se o `loop` iria repetir `10 vezes`, então a função recursiva precisa ser chamada `10 vezes`. A expressão `a > 0 && a >= b` é quem garante isso. Caso não tenha ficado muito claro eu recomendo você fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo).

Veja seu código funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/XP9FBA).

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que para você usar a recursividade teria que chamar o método dentro dele mesmo, por exemplo:

```
int divide (a,b){
    
    int i = 0;

    while (a > 0 && a >= b){
    a = a - b;
    i++;
    
    return divide(a, b);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Oi Bruno, agradeço a resposta! No entanto se eu uso o return divide(a, b), o resultado ainda permanece o mesmo de antes... Também percebi que na maior parte das vezes o valor de i acaba sendo igual ao valor de b (não sei se ele acabou fazendo o cálculo errado ou se deu algum conflito entre as variáveis).