# O que o computador faz com 2 valores distintos que precisam ser retornados e estão no mesmo escopo de memória?

Tags: c, recursão, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Possuo esse código com essa única função, ela realiza o produto entre 'a' e 'b' que recebe da função "main". Gostaria de saber como a função contida nesse código lida com o retorno de 2 valores para o "escopo de cima", se fizerem um teste de mesa do que ela está fazendo, vão perceber que dentro de um mesmo escopo ela tem que retornar dois valores distintos, o que ela faz com esses valores então? Soma? Pois se a resposta for soma mesmo, cheguei no resultado certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int funcao (int a, int b)
{
    if (b==0)
        return 0;

    if (b%2==0)
        return funcao(a+a, b/2);

    return funcao(a+a, b/2)+a;
}

int main () 
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Entre com 'a' e 'b' respectivamente: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    printf("Resultado: %d", funcao(a,b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *...executa os dois returns...* Não! Ao encontrar a primeira instrução `return` a execução da função é interrompida e fluxo de processamento é devolvido ao ponto onde a função foi chamada retornando o valor da expressão passado ao `return` ou `void` se não nada for passado.

Comment: Certo, então está dizendo que quando ela retorna de um escopo, ela ignora o return em que está e passa para o segundo return, que é o responsável por retornar algum valor ao escopo de cima, é isso?

Comment: Eu estou dizendo que ao encontrar exatamente o primeiro `return` a função para  e é retorna com um valor exatamente no ponto onde a função foi anteriormente chamada. Tudo o que estiver após o return é ignorado.

Comment: Entendo o que diz, você está me explicando a natureza do return como desvio de fluxo, e eu havia perguntando sobre sua atuação dentro do meu código, mesmo assim consegui entender, obrigado. Contudo, acho que não me expressei bem, vou reformular, uma função que recebe um valor x do escopo de memória anterior, e dentro de seu escopo atual gera outro valor para retornar, que é o caso da minha, o que ela faz com esses dois valores distintos, soma? Vou até editar a pergunta

Comment: Aonde no seu código estão sendo retornados dois valores? Aqui `return 0;` retorna zero, aqui `funcao(a+a, b/2);` retorna o resultado da função e aqui `return funcao(a+a, b/2)+a;` retorna o resultado da função mais `a`.

Comment: Isso é uma função recursiva, pra entender melhor, sugiro ler [aqui](/q/4282/112052), [aqui](/q/186269/112052) e [aqui](/q/46012/112052). No seu caso, em nenhum lugar a função retorna 2 valores, em todos os `return`'s, sempre é retornado apenas um. Só que em alguns casos, o valor é calculado usando o resultado de uma chamada recursiva (mas ainda é um valor só)

Comment: É mais para o lado do que o hkotsubo disse, fiz essa chamada para entenderem o que eu falo: https://ibb.co/LpTSwSh

Comment: 'F' seria a função, notem que F(16,2) por exemplo, recebe '0' do escopo anterior e gera 16 em seu escopo, F(8,4) recebe 16 do escopo anterior e gera 8 em seu escopo, até voltar ao início

Comment: O que quero saber, é se é um padrão o C somar, por exemplo, recebeu 16 do escopo anterior e gerou 8 no escopo atual, antes de retornar ao escopo de cima então ele tem que somar 8+16, certo?

Comment: Não seria isso o que está tentando fazer https://ideone.com/iTOWKU . Essa frase F(16,2) por exemplo, recebe '0' do escopo anterior não faz sentido. O que é trocado de informações entre contextos de funções são os parâmetro como entrada e valor retornado como saída.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, segue uma sugestão de leitura que pode ajudar no entendimento de funções de forma geral: [*O que acontece quando chamamos uma função?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/112052).

Dito isso, acho que primeiro podemos ver como seria se a `funcao` **não** fosse recursiva, e depois vemos como a versão recursiva não muda tanto assim. Então vamos modificar um pouco a `funcao` para que ela não seja mais recursiva:

```
int funcao(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (b % 2 == 0) // em vez de chamar "funcao", estou chamando "outra_funcao"
        return outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2);
    return outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a;
}

int outra_funcao(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (b % 2 == 0)
        return outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2);
    return outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a;
}
```

`outra_funcao` é praticamente igual à `funcao`, com a diferença que a `funcao` original não é mais recursiva.

---

O que acontece quando chamamos `funcao(3, 1)`?

Neste caso, a função receberá os valores `3` e `1`, que correspondem aos parâmetros `a` e `b`. Ou seja, para `funcao(3, 1)`, temos que `a=3` e `b=1`.

Por isso o código não entra no primeiro `if`, já que `b` não é igual a zero. E como `b` é um número ímpar, então `b % 2` é `1`, por isso ele também não entra no segundo `if`.

Então ele cai no último `return`, que é:

```
return outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a
```

Ou seja, a `funcao` **está retornando apenas um valor**. Esse valor é o resultado da expressão `outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a`. E esta expressão está fazendo basicamente duas coisas:

- chamando `outra_funcao(a + a, b / 2)`
- pegando o resultado da chamada acima e somando com `a`

O resultado disso tudo é o valor retornado por `funcao`. Em nenhum momento tem 2 valores sendo retornados. Temos apenas uma chamada de função (`outra_funcao`), cujo resultado é somado com outro valor (no caso, `a`), e o resultado dessas operações vira um único valor, que é retornado pela `funcao`.

Bom, como chamamos `funcao(3, 1)`, temos que `a=3` e `b=1`, então a expressão acima acaba virando:

```
return outra_funcao(3 + 3, 1 / 2) + 3
```

Que por sua vez acaba virando:

```
return outra_funcao(6, 0) + 3
// como são inteiros, 1 / 2 é "arredondado" para zero
```

Ou seja, para saber o resultado desta expressão, precisamos saber o valor de `outra_funcao(6, 0)`.

E quando chamamos `outra_funcao(6, 0)`, temos `a=6` e `b=0` (esses `a` e `b` dentro de `outra_funcao` não são os mesmos `a` e `b` da `funcao`). Neste caso, entrará no primeiro `if`, e por isso ela retorna zero.

Ou seja, `return outra_funcao(6, 0) + 3` é o mesmo que `return 0 + 3`, que é o mesmo que `return 3`. Concluindo, `funcao(3, 1)` retorna `3`.

---

Mas repare que `funcao` e `outra_funcao` fazem basicamente a mesma coisa. Então para que ter duas funções redundantes, quando eu posso ter uma só?

```
int funcao(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (b % 2 == 0)
        return funcao(a + a, b / 2);
    return funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a;
}
```

Agora `funcao` é [recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186269/112052) (ela é chamada dentro dela mesma). Apesar disso, seu funcionamento continua basicamente o mesmo:

- chamei `funcao(3, 1)`, ou seja, `a=3` e `b=1`

  - não entra em nenhum dos `if`'s, ou seja, cai no `return funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a`
  - que por sua vez, é o mesmo que `return funcao(3 + 3, 1 / 2) + 3`, que é o mesmo que `return funcao(6, 0) + 3`
  - então agora preciso calcular `funcao(6, 0)` - é outra chamada de função (só porque chamou a mesma `funcao`, não muda o fato de ser outra chamada "independente")

    - em `funcao(6, 0)`, temos que `a=6` e `b=0` (como é **outra** chamada de função, esses `a` e `b` não são os mesmos da primeira chamada)
    - como `b=0`, entra no primeiro `if` e retorna zero
  - como `funcao(6, 0)` retornou zero, a expressão `return funcao(6, 0) + 3` é o mesmo que `return 0 + 3`, que é o mesmo que `return 3`
- ou seja, `funcao(3, 1)` retorna `3`

Em nenhum momento há o "retorno de dois valores". A `funcao` sempre retorna **apenas um** valor. O que acontece é que em alguns casos o valor é obtido através de uma expressão que pode envolver outra chamada de função (e não importa se é a mesma função ou outra, a ideia é a mesma: temos que obter o valor retornado pela chamada para poder calcular o resultado final da expressão).

Não existe essa coisa de "escopo de cima", "escopo anterior", nada disso. É apenas uma função que pode chamar outra, que pode chamar outra, que pode chamar outra (sendo que essa "outra" pode ser inclusive a mesma função, com argumentos diferentes). O importante é que todas essas chamadas não fiquem se chamando eternamente, e que em algum momento elas retornem algum valor, que será usado pela chamada anterior, que será usado pela anterior a esta, e assim por diante, até chegar à primeira chamada, que retornará o resultado final.

---

Outro exemplo: `funcao(3, 4)`. Temos que:

- `a=3` e `b=4`, entra no segundo `if`, então retorna `funcao(a + a, b / 2)` → `funcao(6, 2)`

  - `funcao(6, 2)` → `a=6` e `b=2`, entra no segundo `if`, então retorna `funcao(a + a, b / 2)` → `funcao(12, 1)`

    - `funcao(12, 1)` → `a=12` e `b=1`, não entra em nenhum `if`, retorna `funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a` → `funcao(24, 0) + 12`

      - `funcao(24, 0)` → `a=24` e `b=0`, entra no primeiro `if`, retorna zero
    - `funcao(12, 1)` retorna `funcao(24, 0) + 12` → `0 + 12` → `12`
  - `funcao(6, 12)` retorna `funcao(12, 1)` → `12`
- `funcao(3, 4)` retorna `funcao(6, 2)` → `12`

Ou seja, o resultado é 12.

Outra forma de visualizar:

[image: chamada recursiva]

Se a imagem acima não carregar, segue o mesmo diagrama em ASCII:

```
+- funcao(3, 4) --------------------------------------------+
|  a=3, b=4                                                 |
|  entra no segundo if                                      |
|  retorna funcao(6, 2)                                     |
|              ↓                                            |
|       +- funcao(6, 2) ---------------------------------+  |
|       |  a=6, b=2                                      |  |
|       |  entra no segundo if                           |  |
|       |  retorna funcao(12, 1)                         |  |
|       |              ↓                                 |  |
|       |       +- funcao(12, 1) ---------------------+  |  |
|       |       |  a=12, b=1                          |  |  |
|       |       |  não entra em nenhum if             |  |  |
|       |       |  retorna funcao(24, 0)  + 12 ----+  |  |  |
|       |       |              ↓                   |  |  |  |
|       |       |       +- funcao(24, 0) -------+  |  |  |  |
|       |       |       |  a=24, b=0            |  |  |  |  |
|       |       |       |  entra no primeiro if |  |  |  |  |
|       |       |       |  retorna zero         |  |  |  |  |
|       |       |       +---------- | ----------+  |  |  |  |
|       |       |                   ↓              |  |  |  |
|       |       |  retorna          0  +  12 ←-----+  |  |  |
|       |       |  retorna 12                         |  |  |
|       |       +---------- | ------------------------+  |  |
|       |                   |                            |  |
|       |  retorna 12 ←-----+                            |  |
|       +---------- |------------------------------------+  |
|                   |                                       |
|  retorna 12 ←-----+                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Repetindo: não existe essa história de "escopo de cima", de baixo, anterior, etc. O que temos são chamadas de função. Quando você chama uma função, ela é executada, e só depois que ela retorna, o código que chamou a função continua de onde parou. Quando uma função chama outra (ou ela mesma), ela tem que esperar a chamada terminar, para só depois pegar o resultado retornado e poder usá-lo.

Não tem essa história de "*o padrão do C é somar*" (como perguntado nos comentários). **Foi você que disse que deve fazer uma soma**:

```
funcao(a + a, b / 2) + a
                     ↑
         Aqui você disse para somar
```

Esse código soma o resultado de `funcao(a + a, b / 2)` com `a`. Só que para fazer esta soma, ele precisa saber o resultado de `funcao(a + a, b / 2)` - então ela chama a função novamente para saber qual é esse resultado (só que essa chamada pode acabar fazendo outra chamada, que pode fazer outra, e outra, etc, até que em algum momento elas caem no primeiro `if` e começam a retornar os resultados para quem as chamou).

Se em vez dessa soma, tivesse qualquer outra operação (subtração, multiplicação, outra chamada de função, ou qualquer outra expressão válida), ela seria feita. O "padrão" não é somar, é chamar as funções, pegar os resultados e usá-los da forma que o código indica - se o código diz para somar, como é o caso, ele soma.

Enfim, é "só" isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, finalmente tive tempo de fazer a leitura desse seu texto e entendi perfeitamente o comportamento dessa função recursiva através de seu diagrama, executei algumas vezes com valores diferentes e deu certo aqui, fico muito grato.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi, mas ela não está retornando dois valores. Está retornando a soma de 'a + (chamada da propria função ( valor a,valor b))'.

Entradas e ciclos da função recursiva:
input a == 2, b == 2

recursividade:

Entra 2,2 -> Respeita o segundo if que gera os inputs -> 4,1 -> Entra no ultimo return que gera os inputs (8,0.5) somado com 4 ( (a+a,b/2) +a) nessa parte o (8,0.5) gera 0 que somados com 4  resulta em 4. Com isso respeita a entrada 2*2 = 4.

Entra 3,3 -> Entra no ultimo return que gera (6,1.5)+3 -> O (6,1.5) entra na ultima condição que gera (12,(1.5)/2)+6   - > o input (12,(1.5/2) entra na primeira condição que retorna 0, logo fica 6+3 = 9.

Não sei pra que essa mirabolância toda, mas funciona. Espero ter ajudado