# Qual o nome de uma recursividade que não é de cauda?

Tags: funções, recursão, programação-funcional

Na recursividade de cauda, a chamada recursiva é a última coisa que a função faz, podendo ser otimizada.

E quando não é de cauda? Como é o nome? "Comum"? "De corpo"? Deve haver um nome específico para isso!

Comment: Os termos mais usados são: **recursāo**, **recursão comum** e **recursão tradicional**, em contraste à **recursão de cauda**.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184494/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-recurs%C3%A3o-de-cauda

Answer (score 2):

A **recursão de cauda** é uma técnica de recursão que faz menos uso de memória durante o processo de
empilhamento, o que a torna mais rápida que a recursão comum.

Em uma **recursão comum**, a cada chamada recursiva realizada, é necessário guardar a posição do código
onde foi feita a chamada para que continue a partir dali assim que receber o resultado.

#### Referência:

- [http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~oliveira/doc/mc102_2s2004/Aula19.pdf](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Eoliveira/doc/mc102_2s2004/Aula19.pdf)

Comment: Dupicada: [Qual a diferença entre recursão e recursão de cauda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4282/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-recurs%c3%a3o-e-recurs%c3%a3o-de-cauda)