# Dúvidas com recursão em cauda em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Olá, gostaria de saber como se baseia a recursão em cauda nessa linguagem. Não compreendi o porque desse 1 na parte: "*fatcalda n = fataux n 1*". gostaria que me ajudassem por favor!

```
fatcalda :: Integer -> Integer
fatcalda n = fataux n 1
       where
             fataux n parcial | n == 0 = parcial
                              | n > 0 = fataux (n-1) (n*parcial)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você já saiba o que é recursão em cauda (caso não sabia, recomendo que leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4282/)), o argumento `1` se contra ali apenas para garantir que a `fataux` seja chamada corretamente.

Nesta implementação de `fatcalda` (ou seria `fatcauda`?), a função que faz todo o trabalho é `fataux`, sendo que o segundo argumento é usado como acumulador para que haja recursão em cauda. Mas para que `fatcalda` calcule propriamente o valor de um fatorial, `fataux` deve sempre ser "inicializada" com um acumulador igual a 1. Se `fataux` começar com um acumulador com valor diferente de 1, o resultado de  `fatcalda n` seria diferente de fatorial de `n`.

É importante notar também que `fataux` está definida apenas dentro do escopo de `fatcalda` e, portanto, ela só pode ser chamada pela própria `fatcalda`, ou outra função que possa existir no mesmo escopo. Como `fatcalda n` sempre chama `fataux n 1`, está garantido que o resultado será o fatorial.

Faça o teste você mesmo no GHCi: defina `fataux` fora de `fatcalda` e teste-a com o segundo argumento com valores diferentes de 1.

```
Prelude> fataux n parcial | n == 0 = parcial | n > 0 = fataux (n-1) (n*parcial)
Prelude> fatcalda n = fataux n 1
Prelude> fatcalda 5 -- 1*2*3*4*5 = 120 (correto)
120
Prelude> fataux 5 1 -- 1*2*3*4*5 = 120 (correto)
120
Prelude> fataux 5 2 -- 2*2*3*4*5 = 240 (errado)
240
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, seria "fatcauda". Muito obrigado, pude compreender melhor sobre o assunto!   :)