# Programa recursivo que aceita um inteiro não negativo como entrada e exibe seus dígitos empilhados verticalmente

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Desenvolvi a função recursiva `vertical()`, que aceita um inteiro não negativo como entrada e exibe seus dígitos empilhados verticalmente.

Por exemplo:

```
>>> vertical(3124)
3
1
2
4
```

Solução:

```
def vertical(n):
    if n< 10:
        print(n)
    else:
        vertical(n//10)
        print(n%10)

n = 3124
vertical(n)
```

Alguém poderia me explicar passo a passo como funciona a solução recursiva acima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Uma dica para entender o funcionamento de qualquer algoritmo é fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052). Tudo bem que para algoritmos recursivos pode ser um pouco mais confuso, mas de qualquer forma vale a tentativa.*</sup>

---

A ideia básica da recursão é resolver o problema de maneira... recursiva, ou seja, você resolve uma instância menor do mesmo problema, usando o mesmo algoritmo (e caso não seja [recursão em cauda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/112052), você junta os resultados depois).

No seu caso, como seria um algoritmo recursivo para mostrar os dígitos de um número empilhados? Basicamente, seria algo assim:

1. se o número só tem um dígito, basta imprimir o próprio número e pronto
2. se o número tem mais de um dígito (vamos supor que a quantidade é **N** dígitos):

   - 2.1. imprima os N - 1 primeiros dígitos empilhados
   - 2.2. imprima o último dígito

O passo 1 acima corresponde ao `if n < 10` (com o detalhe que não vai funcionar muito bem com números negativos, e a função poderia até verificar este caso e dar um erro, por exemplo, mas enfim). Esse é o caso básico, no qual não é necessário fazer nenhuma chamada recursiva.

O passo 2 corresponde ao `else`, quando o número tem mais de um dígito e precisamos da chamada recursiva.

Mas como resolver o passo 2.1? Simples, você executa **o mesmo algoritmo**, mas em vez de considerar todos os dígitos, você considera somente os N - 1 primeiros (ou seja, você chama a mesma função recursivamente, passando um número que só tem os N - 1 primeiros dígitos, e depois que ela retornar, você executa o passo 2.2).

No caso do número 3124, ficaria assim:

- 3124 é menor que 10? Não, entra no `else`, que chama `vertical(3124 // 10)`, ou seja, `vertical(312)` (o operador `//` é a [divisão inteira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/183870), ou seja, ignorando as casas decimais do resultado). Esse é o passo 2.1, chamei a função recursivamente, passando somente os N - 1 primeiros dígitos.

  - agora estamos dentro da chamada `vertical(312)`:
  - 312 é menor que 10? Não, entra no `else`, que chama `vertical(312 // 10)`, ou seja, `vertical(31)` - novamente, é o passo 2.1

    - agora estamos dentro da chamada `vertical(31)`:
    - 31 é menor que 10? Não, entra no `else`, que chama `vertical(31 // 10)`, ou seja, `vertical(3)` - mais uma vez executamos o passo 2.1

      - agora estamos dentro da chamada `vertical(3)`:
      - 3 é menor que 10? Sim, imprime `3` e a função encerra a sua execução (ou seja, a chamada `vertical(3)` não tem mais o que fazer e se encerra)
    - ainda estamos dentro da chamada `vertical(31)`, e agora podemos executar o passo 2.2, que é imprimir o valor de `31 % 10` - o [resto da divisão](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) de 31 por 10, ou seja, `1`.
  - ainda estamos dentro da chamada `vertical(312)`, e agora podemos executar o passo 2.2, que é imprimir o valor de `312 % 10`, ou seja, `2`
- ainda estamos dentro da chamada `vertical(3124)`, e agora podemos executar o passo 2.2, que é imprimir o valor de `3124 % 10`, ou seja, `4`

Assim, o algoritmo imprime `3`, `1`, `2` e `4`, nesta ordem.
O que pode confundir é o fato de que a cada chamada recursiva o contexto muda: o número sendo analisado é outro, embora o algoritmo seja o mesmo.

Outro detalhe é que a cada chamada que entra no `else`, o passo 2.2 precisa esperar o passo 2.1 terminar. Mas como o passo 2.1 é a chamada recursiva, ela pode chamar novamente o passo 2.1, que faz outra chamada recursiva (e precisa esperar ela retornar para executar seu próprio passo 2.2) e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

A ideia da recursão sub dividir o problema em problemas
menores para que possa ser resolvido

```
 def vertical(n):
    if n < 10:
        print(n)
    else:
        vertical(n//10) # // divisão inteira 
        print(n%10) # modulo da divisão


# entrada

n = 3124
vertical(n) # n = 3124
vertical(n) # n = 312
vertical(n) # n = 31
vertical(n) # n = 3
```

funcionamento algoritmo vai executar todas as recursões passando divisão inteira ate ele cair no caso
base que seria n < 10 e vai resolver debaixo para cima você pode pensar que ele coloca 
em uma pilha e depois remove da pilha obtendo o resultado na vertical para obter
os resultados ele vai tirando modulo da divisão no print

```
3 
1 
2 
4
```

Comment: Teria como detalhar um pouco mais? Este programa em específico me deixou confuso.